# Sending two dimensional byte array(multiple files) through postman as a multi part request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, postman

I have a rest endpoint developed in spring. it consumes a multi part request with a string as one part(meta) and a two dimensional byte array(documents) as a second part. I was able to push the data using code.
but I want to test the rest endpoint using postman

I have tried with sending the request part key as

1. documents[0] - file ,documents[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k04zB.png) - file [image]
2. documents - multiple files
3. documents [ ] - files
4. specifically added the content-type as multi-part form data
5. specifically added content-type for each key as well.
   the above approaches didn't work.

[image]
can someone suggest me on how to send a two dimensional byte array through postman to spring rest endpoint.

Comment: can you post your REST method's signature?

Comment: @robingood Updated the question with screenshot

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to get the byte[][] from? Do you have a string of two dimensional array? Can you please load a sample of the content of the data which you are sending exactly as you are sending it?

Comment: @Stempler I'm sending multiple files as a two dimensional byte array.

Comment: @Kaiizok, could you explain more about two dimensional byte array? I can see only one dimension from Postman screenshot.

Comment: @John the request part is where I'm trying to receive a two dimensional byte array. The postman request is the testing way I tried pushing multiple documents to receive it as two dimensional byte array

Answer (score 1):

You can use `List<MultipartFile>`/`MultipartFile[]` in the controller method argument which you can get `byte[]` for each uploaded files from each `MultipartFile` . It also allows you to get the original file name , size and the content type for each upload file.

Code wise it looks like:

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/testMultiPart")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity testMultiPart(
    @RequestPart("meta") Map<String,String> meta,  
    @RequestPart("documents") List<MultipartFile> docs){


    for(MultipartFile file: docs){
        //Get the byte array for this file
        byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

        System.out.println("OriginalFilename:" + file.getOriginalFilename());
        System.out.println("FileSize:" + file.getSize());
        System.out.println("ContentType:" + file.getContentType());

    }
}
```

Comment: This approach is working one, but is there any way I can receive it without modifying anything. I want the request part to be a two dimensional byte array.
Can you suggest some other approach ?

Comment: if what you want to achieve is "without modifying anything" , then it cannot because this is how it works. The most similar things that you can achieve is using `MultipartFile[]`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?

```
documents[0,0]
documents[0,1]
documents[1,0]
documents[0,1]
...
```